# How can I input a single additional parameter to disk.frame's inmapfn at readin?

Tags: r, tidyverse, disk.frame

According to the article https://diskframe.com/articles/ingesting-data.html a good use case for inmapfn as part of `csv_to_disk_frame(...)` is for date conversion. In my data I know the name of the date column at runtime and would like to feed in the date to a convert at read in time function. One issue I am having is that it doesn't seem any additional parameters can be passed into the inmapfn argument beyond the chunk itself. I can't use a hardcoded variable at runtime as the name of the column isn't known until runtime.

To clarify the issue is that the inmapfn seems to run in its own environment to prevent any data races/other parallelisation issues but I know the variable won't be changed so I am hoping there is someway to override this as I can make sure that this is safe.

I know the function I am calling works when called on an arbitrary dataframe.

I have provided a reproducible example below.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(disk.frame)

setup_disk.frame()

a <- tribble(~dates, ~val,
             "09feb2021", 2,
             "21feb2012", 2,
             "09mar2013", 3,
             "20apr2021", 4,
)

write_csv(a, "a.csv")

dates_col <- "dates"

tmp.df <- csv_to_disk.frame(
  "a.csv",
  outdir = file.path(tempdir(), "tmp.df"),
  in_chunk_size = 1L, 
  inmapfn = function(chunk) {
    chunk[, sdate := as.Date(do.call(`$`, list(chunk,dates_col)), "%d%b%Y")]
  }
)
#>  -----------------------------------------------------
#> Stage 1 of 2: splitting the file a.csv into smallers files:
#> Destination: C:\Users\joelk\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcFBBkr\file4a1876e87bf5
#>  -----------------------------------------------------
#> Stage 1 of 2 took: 0.020s elapsed (0.000s cpu)
#>  -----------------------------------------------------
#> Stage 2 of 2: Converting the smaller files into disk.frame
#>  -----------------------------------------------------
#> csv_to_disk.frame: Reading multiple input files.
#> Please use `colClasses = `  to set column types to minimize the chance of a failed read
#> =================================================
#> 
#>  -----------------------------------------------------
#> -- Converting CSVs to disk.frame -- Stage 1 of 2:
#> 
#> Converting 5 CSVs to 6 disk.frames each consisting of 6 chunks
#> 
#> Error in do.call(`$`, list(chunk, dates_col)): object 'dates_col' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can experiment with different `backend` and `chunk_reader` arguments.  For example, if you set the `backend` to `readr`, the `inmapfn` user defined function will have access to previously defined variables. Furthermore, `readr` will do column type guessing
and will automatically impute Date type columns if it recognizes the string format as a date (in your example data it wouldn't recognize that as a date type, however).

If you don't want to use the readr backend for performance reasons, then I would ask if your example correctly represents your actual scenario?  I'm not seeing the need to pass in the date column as a variable in the example you provided.

There is a working solution in the [Just-in-time transformation](https://diskframe.com/articles/ingesting-data.html#just-in-time-transformation) section of the link you provided, and I'm not seeing any added complexities between that example and yours.

If you really need to use the default `backend` and `chunk_reader` plan AND you *really* need to send the inmapfn function a previously defined variable, you can wrap the the `csv_to_disk.frame` call in a wrapper function:

```
library(disk.frame)

setup_disk.frame()

df <- tribble(~dates, ~val,
              "09feb2021", 2,
              "21feb2012", 2,
              "09mar2013", 3,
              "20apr2021", 4,
)

write.csv(df, file.path(tempdir(), "df.csv"), row.names = FALSE)

wrap_csv_to_disk <- function(col) {
  
  my_date_col <- col
  
  csv_to_disk.frame(
    file.path(tempdir(), "df.csv"), 
    in_chunk_size = 1L,
    inmapfn = function(chunk, dates = my_date_col) {
      chunk[, dates] <- lubridate::dmy(chunk[[dates]])
      chunk
    })
}

date_col <- "dates"

df_disk_frame <- wrap_csv_to_disk(date_col)

#> str(collect(df_disk_frame)$dates)
# Date[1:4], format: "2021-02-09" "2012-02-21" "2013-03-09" "2021-04-20"
```

Comment: I think this answers my question and will give a go with readr. My real data contains tens of millions of rows and performance is important so if it doesn't  work quickly enough I will edit the question or upload a new one.

Comment: In that case, I edited the solution to more closely reflect what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see. For a work around would it be possible to do something like this?

```
date_var = knonw_at_runtime()
saveRDS(date_var, "some/path/date_var.rds")

a = csv_to_disk.frame(files, inmapfn = function(chunk) {
   date_var = readRDS("some/path/date_var.rds")
   # do the rest
})
```

I think letting `inmapfn` have other options is doable see https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame/issues/377 for tracking